# Where's the best place to find Authorize.net developer?

Tags: freelance-websites

I want to hire someone to integrate Authorize.net with the Wordpress plug-in WPJobBoard. There are instructions for adding a new payment method on their website but I'd rather pay someone than spend time figuring it out. Is Upwork.com the best place to try to find freelance help for something like this? Or are there other resources?

The problem I have with Upwork is I have to post the job and a price. I'd rather post a job and have someone say they can do it for X amount.

Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gary/Drew,
I can tell you how much it should cost for the average payment plugin. For a US based developer you would expect 10-20 hours and hourly rate would range from 40-85/hr.

For an offshore solution you will look at the same time but hourly range from $20-$40/hr

The good thing is an auth.net plugin is a fairly basic connection compared to most out there and likely many have the experience in it's API.

I have used the freelancing sites for years now and find there are certain regions that have better quality coders than others but the best thing is to find your own regulars if you have more than one project. Don't give out your cpanel access, ftp only and your WP logins then change them after. And make sure you have your SSL installed before work. You will need a secure site to process credit cards.

Comment: This is good info. Thank you. The only freelancing sites I'm familiar with are Upwork (formerly elance) and Freelancer.com. Are there other sites? Better? Thanks again.

Comment: Did you get your plugin built? If not, I can have my developer do it for you.  We have an authorize.net development account to test it before delivery. Not free of course but if you need someone let me know.